# Prove that $A \cap B = A \Rightarrow B^{c} \subseteq A^{c}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Prove that $A \cap B = A \Rightarrow B^{c} \subseteq A^{c}$

My attempt:

Let $x\in B^{c}$. We want to show that $\forall x \in B^{c}, x\in A^{c}$

Since $x\in B^{c}, x\notin B$

And since $A \cap B = A$, This means $x \in A$ and $x \notin A^{c}$

Thus, $A \cap B = A \nRightarrow B^{c} \subseteq A^{c}$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continue like this; Since $x\in B^{c}, x\notin B$

and hence  $x\notin A \cap B = A$, This means $x \notin A$ and therefore $x \in A^{c}.$

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct but how you conclude $x\notin B$ and $A\cap B=A$ gives $x\in A$.

Another way:
$$B^c\subset B^c\cup A^c=(B\cap A)^c=A^c$$

Answer (score 2):

I think your third line in the proof is not quite right. You have that $x \notin B \implies x \notin A \cap B = A$. Thus, $x \in A^C$

You could also prove this using de Morgans laws: Assume $A \cap B = A$. We have

$$(A \cap B)^C = A^C \implies A^C \cup B^C = A^C \implies B^C \subseteq A^C$$